# Multicast routing using netplan

Tags: routing, multicast, netplan

Trying to setup multicast route to interface in Ubuntu 18.04.2 Netplan's syntax does not allow something like:

```
routes:
 - to: 224.0.0.0/4
   dev: eno1
```

this config does not work:

```
addresses:
 - 192.160.0.1/24
routes:
 - to: 224.0.0.0/4
   via: 192.168.0.1
```

how to set-up multicast route correctly?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.04, If you only setup `to:` you would receive a warning saying:

```
Error in network definition: unicast route must include both a 'to' and 'via' IP
```

It seems to assume that the route is a unicast route. However `via` is not necessary when adding a multicast route.

The correct configuration is:

```
    ens224:
      addresses:
      - 192.160.0.1/24
      routes:
      - to: 224.0.0.0/4
        scope: link
```

This will result in the following route to be added:

```
224.0.0.0/4 dev ens224 proto static scope link
```

`scope:` is described at:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/netplan.5.html
and more precisely at:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/ip-route.8.html

```
              scope SCOPE_VAL
                     the scope of the destinations covered by the route prefix.  SCOPE_VAL may be
                     a number or a string from the file /etc/iproute2/rt_scopes.  If this
                     parameter is omitted, ip assumes scope global for all gatewayed unicast
                     routes, scope link for direct unicast and broadcast routes and scope host
                     for local routes.
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs are not super clear indeed but we've had some luck with the following:

```
routes:
  - to: 224.0.0.0/4
    via: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: how will system decide in this case from which interface to send traffic?